# Multiple SCSS equations to work out width minus margin

Tags: sass

I have a mixin that splits items of a users choosing into an inline-block grid. Users can specify how many in a row, gutter and the child element to target.

This all works fine and an example is below:

**Original - SCSS**

```
@mixin list-grid($per-row, $spacing, $selector){
    margin: 0 em(-$spacing/2);
    @include clearfix;
    //negate the display-inline biatch
    letter-spacing: -0.31em;

    > #{$selector} {
        width: 100% / $per-row;
        font-size: 16px;
        position: relative;
        padding: 0 em($spacing/2) em($spacing) em($spacing/2);
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        letter-spacing: 0;
        background-clip: content-box;
    }
}
```

My question is.. When i try and use margin I need to rework the calculations as previously this worked because padding is not accounted when working out widths, whereas now with margin I need to adjust the widths to account for the chosen margin.

I'm not sure how to best approach this. Any help appreciated.

**New Attempt - SCSS**

```
@mixin list-grid($per-row, $spacing, $selector){
    margin: 0 em(-$spacing/2);
    @include clearfix;
    //negate the display-inline biatch
    letter-spacing: -0.31em;

    > #{$selector} {
        /* not sure what to do here */
        width: 100% / $per-row -$spacing;
        font-size: 16px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 em($spacing/2) em($spacing) em($spacing/2);
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        letter-spacing: 0;
        background-clip: content-box;
    }
}
```

The latest attempt ends up with a width of 8% if I do a row of 3, with 25 gutter. My math must be way off.

[Working example](http://codepen.io/vdecree/pen/DwAdF)

Comment: Can you provide some *expected values*?

Comment: Updating with working example

Comment: Would I need to introduce another argument and get a max-width in order to turn the px margin input, into a percentage?

Comment: It's still not clear what your expected values are.  It's also not clear why you would do this over using the multi-column module:  http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/CcGlE

Comment: The only reason was that css columns is only partially supported still, from my knowledge. Though css columns is sure easy